# How to find intersection point between circle and line(2 points) using Mapbox(Turf)

Tags: java, mapbox, intersection, line-intersection

I'm finding how to find intersection point between circle and line(2 points) using Mapbox(Turf).

Turfjs provides "intersect" function but Turf in java doesn't provide that function.

I wonder how to calculate intersection point(longitude and latitude).

My code below:

```java
public void circleIntersectionPointTest() {
        Point circleCenter = Point.fromLngLat(1.0, 1.0);
        double circleRadius = 35; //nautical mile
        Polygon circle = TurfTransformation.circle(circleCenter, circleRadius, TurfConstants.UNIT_NAUTICAL_MILES);

        Point innerPoint = Point.fromLngLat(1.0, 0.5);
        Point outerPoint = Point.fromLngLat(2.0, 1.5);

        //how to find between circle and line with innerPoint and outerPoint
        Point intersectionPoint;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's how you do it:

1. Find the angle: The angle (in radians) is

   ```
    double xdiff = x1 - x2;
    double ydiff = y1 - y2;
    //double tan = xdiff / ydiff;
    double atan = Math.atan2(ydiff, xdiff);
    return atan;
   ```
2. Now you can find the point on the circle, via

   ```
   circleCenter.x + sin(angle) * circleRadius, circleCenter.y + cos(angle) * circleRadius
   ```

It's been a while and you should check that I am invoking atan2 the right way, and cosine should be applied to the x parameter and sin to the y parameter - the way trigonometry is taught in school, angles go the opposite way as how we think of them on a compass, so there's some confusion here. But this should give you the idea of how to solve this.

For more, you can check

https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/MathUtils.java